# Strange spikes in my surface

Tags: plotting

I'm getting strange spikes in my surface `S` with the code below. `PlotPoints` seems to help, but it doesn't solve the problem. Any explanation and solution would be much appreciated.

```
a := {x, y, 1 - x}
b := {x, y, x}
S := Inner[Times, 
  Transpose[Inner[Times, {1 - x, x}, {{a /. {x -> 0, y -> 0}, b /. {x -> 0, y -> 1}},
     {a /. {x -> 1, y -> 0}, b /. {x -> 1, y -> 1}}}, Plus]], {1 - y, y}, Plus]
ParametricPlot3D[S, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
ParametricPlot3D[S, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotPoints -> 100]
Expand[S]
ParametricPlot3D[{x, y, 1 - x - y + 2 x y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

---

EDIT: It seems that `y ->` is somehow responsible.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I can't see your spikes with Mma 9.0 WinXP

Comment: I can see them (9.0.1 on Mac)

Comment: Thanks for checking. I'm on Win8 with MMA 9.0.1. I briefely edited out the `y -> 0` here because I thought it was redundant for my MWE. Now it's back in. It does matter in full code. Without `y -> `, I also don't get spikes. Strange.

Comment: I can see spikes on Vista (Mathematica 9.0).  Conclusions:   Expand helps ?  A related problem where `Expand` had helped in version `8.0` : http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3568/bug-in-integrate-for-mathematica/3571#3571. However that bug has been fixed in ver. `9.0`.

Comment: @Frank Same here

Comment: I can see them on 9.0.1 win7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for the strange behavior is the "strange" definition of `S`.  Compare:

```
Block[{x, y},
 x = 0.6; y = 0.4;
 S]
  (* {0.6, 0.4, 0.24} *)

S /. {x -> 0.6, y -> 0.4}
  (* {0.6, 0.4, 0.48} *)
```

Plot does something like the first one.  What happens is that every `x` is replaced by `0.6` and every `y` is replaced by `0.4`.  So `a = {x, 0, 1 - x}` becomes `{0.6, 0, 0.4}`, and the rules `{x -> 0, y -> 0}` become `{0.6 -> 0, 0.4 -> 0}`.  When applied to `a`, we get `{0, 0, 0}` instead of `{0, 0 1}`.

The following is a possible workaround:

```
ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate @ S, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
```

[Edit: Forgot to put the `Evaluate` in.]