# Why won't Mathematica Integrate my function?

Tags: functions

My code:

```
r5 = 47000;
vcc = 3.3;
hfe = 420; (* BC337-40: 250 *)
vbe = 0.6;
r4 = vbe/2*^-6;
ctr = 1;
r1 = 1000000; r2 = r1;
vrms = 230;
vled = 1.5;
v0[t_] := Max[vcc - r5 ic[t], 0.2]
ic[t_] := Min[hfe ib[t] + 0.000005, vcc/r5]
ib[t_] := idar[t] - ir4[t]
ir4[t_] := Min[idar[t], vbe/r4]
idar[t_] := Abs[iled[t]] ctr
iled[t_] := Max[Sign[vi[t]] (Max[Abs[vi[t]] - vled, 0])/(r1 + r2), 0]
vi[t_] := vrms Sqrt[2]  Sin[2 Pi t/20]
pmains[t_] := vi[t] iled[t]
pvcc[t_] := vcc idar[t] + vcc ic[t]
power[t_] := pmains[t] + pvcc[t]
pvccavg = Integrate[pvcc[t], {t, 0, 20}]/20
```

MMA gives me this result:

[image]

which is my list of nested function calls written as one single function. Why doesn't `Integrate` work here? Note that it does give me results if I split the [0,20] interval in [0,10] and [10,20].

Comment: `NIntegrate` gives you the answer in less than a second

Comment: @R.M. - Yes, OK, Thanks. But I was wondering why Integrate doesn't work, while it does over the two smaller intervals. Does it have to do with the `Abs` and/or `Max` I'm using?

Comment: Integrate requires 1. Symbolic Input 2. a function that it knows how to symbolically solve. The function that you are integrating using floating point numbers instead of rational numbers. This by itself is a problem since symbolic manipulation of floating point  numbers isn't necessarily numerically stable. Additionally, Integrate does not guarantee that it can always find a symbolic solution for an Integral. This is because finding a symbolic solution is often impossible.

Comment: Although really in this case, the solution is a piecewise function, which is easily solved symbolically. Integrate just doesn't seem to have any functionality for converting the Max/Min statements into a piecewise expression.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Plot[pvcc[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

seems to show several discrete regions.

After studying those, this seems to give enough of a hint to accomplish the goal.

```
In[1]:= Integrate[Simplify[pvcc[t], t > 0], {t, 0, 20}]

Out[1]= 0.00585019
```

Comment: Bill Simpson, welcome to the site, and nice answer.  I included an image of the plot for you.

Comment: Another hint of this is that the integral of `vcc idar[t]` is actually done (without the `Simplify`).

Answer (score 4):

Or just use `Nintegrate[]`

```
pvccavg = NIntegrate[pvcc[t], {t, 0, 20}]
```

which gives 0.00587397.

Answer (score 3):

OK, so `NIntegrate` seems to be the solution. But I found a possible reason why symbolic integration doesn't work. Take this indefinite integral:

```
Integrate[Abs[x], x]
```

[image]

It won't do it. Apparently `Abs` sees the argument as complex, because

```
Integrate[Abs[x], x, Assumptions :> Element[x, Reals]
```

*does* work:

[image]

It's not a complete explanation though, because if we make the first form into a definite integral

```
Integrate[Abs[x], {x, -1, 2}]
```

[image]

also works.

Comment: Regarding the `Abs` example: try `Integrate[If[x > 0, x, -x], x]` and now it works. Apparently it assumes a real $x$ for this `If[]` construct (which a priori I'd have thought shouldn't be used for mathematical functions).

Comment: @acl - "which a priori I'd have thought shouldn't be used for mathematical functions". Exactly my thoughts. It's bad enough that my functions are full of `Abs` and `Max`.

Comment: @acl by implying that $x>0$, it must be real. The same thing occurs when specifying the limits on the integral.

Comment: @acl Complementing rcollyer's answer: see [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3509/does-x0-imply-that-x-in-mathbbr).

Comment: @rcollyer but it doesn't, it just says "if x>0". I'm not sure I could have predicted what would happen if I hadn't tried this.